# Calculated overpay amount base on date condition -SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a code in SQL to retrieve member who has pay date after termination date, and now I also need to calculate **the total amount paid after the termination date**. How can I achieve that?

There are 2 table, member table:

[image]

The final out come I want is:

[image]

Currently I am able to retrieve other columns but the Sum(Rcvd Amount)

```
Select Member_ID
       , Term_DT
       , RCVD.MAX_RCVD_DT
From Membership a
Left Join
     (
      Select Member_ID
           , MAX(RCVD_DT) as MAX_RCVD_DT
      from received
      group by Member_ID
      )
 AS RCVD on RCVD.Member_ID = a.Member_ID

 WHERE RCVD.MAX_RCVD_DT >= Term_DT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a join -- with an inequality condition -- and aggregation:

```
select m.memberid, sum(r.rcvd_amount)
from membership m join
     received r
     on m.memberid = r.memberid and
        r.recvd_date > m.term_date
group by m.memberid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use below query:

```
select m.memberid, max(m.Term_DT) Term_DT, MAX(r.RCVD_DT) as MAX_RCVD_DT,  sum(r.rcvd_amount)
from membership m join
     received r
     on m.memberid = r.memberid and
        r.recvd_date > m.term_date
group by m.memberid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select m.Member_ID [Member ID], m.Term_DT [Term Date], 
       sum(r.RCVD_AMOUNT) [Rcvd Amount], max(r.RCVD_DT) [Latest Rcvd Date]
from membership m
     join received r on m.Member_ID = r.Member_ID
                        and r.RCVD_DT >= m.Term_DT
group by m.Member_ID, m.Term_DT;
```